# Extracting a weakly convergent subsequence in $L^1$.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading the paper "A Variational Framework for Exemplar-Based Image Inpainting" and I'm a little confused by their proof of Proposition 1. I'm sure it's a basic analysis result, but I don't see the reasoning. Basically they have a bounded set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $ with $O \subset \Omega$. Now if we let $\left\{w_n \right\} \subset L^1(O \times O^c)$ where the complement is taken in $\Omega$, they say the boundedness of $\Omega$ implies
\begin{equation}
\int_{O} \int_{O^c} \chi_{ \left\{ w_n > 1 \right\} } w_n(x,y) \log w_n (x,y) dy dx
\end{equation} 
is bounded. This further implies $w_n ( 1 + log^+ w_n)$ is bounded in $L^1(O \times O^c)$. Then we are able to conclude the sequence $w_n$ is relatively weakly compact in $L^1$ so that we may extract a weakly convergent subsequence in $L^1(O \times O^c)$.

My questions are:

1. Why is the integral bounded?
2. Why does $w_n(1+log^+ w_n)$ being bounded in $L^1$ imply the sequence is relatively weakly compact in $L^1$?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Pray tell, what is $\mathcal 0$?

Comment: $O$ is some open subset of $\Omega$.